# What does the statement (1<<y) mean in bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am a complete beginner at bitwise operations (and not very experienced at C either) and I bumped into the expression:

```
x |= (1<<y)
```

At first I thought it meant "x equals x or y shifted left by on bit", but then I realized that would be:

```
x |= (y<<1)
```

Lastly I thought it meant "x equals x or 1 shifted left by y bits", but I don't understand where that 1 is in an 8-bit register, does it mean 00000001? so that:

```
a = 2
b = 1<<a // so b=00000010
```

Could someone tell me the correct meaning of this statement. Also, if anyone has a good link explaining bitwise syntax I'd be grateful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x |= ...
```

is shorthand for

```
x = x | ...
```

It assigns the value of `x | ...` to `x`.

```
1 << y
```

is `1` left-shifted by `y`. E.g.

```
00000001 << 1 -> 00000010
```

So,

```
x |= (1 << y)
```

is *`OR` `x` with `1` left shifted by `y` (and assign the result to `x`).*
In other words, it sets the *y'th* bit of `x` to `1`.

```
x = 01010101
x |= (1 << 1)   -> 01010111  (it set the 2nd bit to 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement means left shift the binary representation of 1 (0b0000001) by y bits. Then OR the value with X. 
The assumption is correct for the second statement. 
The third statement will yield 4 (0b0000000100).
In terms of bit operation semantics the C standard defines all bit operations to represented such that binary numbers are read right to left with ascending values of powers of 2. You do not need to worry about endianess or two complements etc, the compiler will handle that for you. So (0b00100) = 4, (0b000010) = 2, (0b00001) = 1, and so on.